# exec('unzip gallery.zip',$return); php

Tags: php, unzip

can any one please let me know, why i could not get result for the php function

```
exec('unzip gallery.zip',$return);
print_r($return);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check the return value from unzip? Error messages are not given on standard output stream, so the array will be empty if something fails.

```
<?php
    $result = array();
    exec("unzip archiv.zip", $result, $returnval);
    print_r($result);
    print_r($returnval);
?>
```

Does the unzip work as expected? It might ask for overwriting etc. if the files already exist and stop the workflow. This output will not be captured in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized variable `$return` before use?

Have you installed package `unzip` if you're running Unix or Linux? (I'm not sure that you can do that on Windows)

Comment: Hi, do i need to enable any commend in php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

Errors are written to stderr and aren't shown when using exec, backticks or shell_exec functions.

[passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) does output the error stream (as well as stdout).

Ps : Its probably either:

**File not found:** Does `gallery.zip` exists in the [cwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). Use absolute paths and [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) te be sure.

or

**File rights:** Is php allowed to write the extracted files to the cwd or specified targetpath?